# How to do es6 exports with self executing functions in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, promise, es6-modules

In vue, I can do something like

```
components : {
    'my-components' : import(".../file.js")
}
```

then file.js

```
export default {
    a : 1
}
```

The above works, but now I want to do something like

```
export default {
    a : await fetch("data.json")
}
```

but since there is no top level await support yet (https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await), I found I could do this too

```
export default async function() {
    var data = await (await fetch("data.json")).json();
    return { a : data };
}
```

But now the above doesn't work with

```
components : {
    'my-components' : import(".../file.js")
}
```

Then I thought, maybe this will work

```
export default (async function() {
    var data = await (await fetch("data.json")).json();
    return { a : data };
})();
```

since it looks like it's wanting an object itself rather than a function, so self invoking.

But vue doesn't like that either.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Sinice you want to stop execaution until fetch is completed, you need to do synchronous xhr. Or you will have to find a way to work with promises (meaning that everything dependent o that fetch will be promise)

Comment: *In vue, I can do something like* - are you sure? Where does this information come from? Dynamic import returns a promise. If a place where you put a promise supports them then it's ok, otherwise it isn't.

Comment: the first part is from their documentation..

Comment: Is your end goal to load a vue component definition using fetch? And is that component defined in a json file?

Comment: more like just be able to use await in the export.